# can we update list of document field value together in firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to update all document field value together not one by one.

example. in this pic i want to update thumb value in hello.

i also try but value not updated.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('tbl_Messages')
                        .doc("e5df2a37-816b-4b48-830f-d6387cc4d043")
                        .collection('e5df2a37-816b-4b48-830f-d6387cc4d043')
                        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
                        .get()
                        .then((QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                      List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> queryDocumentSnapshot =
                          documentSnapshot.docs;
                      queryDocumentSnapshot.forEach((element) {
                        Map<String, dynamic> message =
                            element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                        message['thumb'] = 'hello';
                        print("thumb value => ${message['thumb']}");
                      });
                    });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fetching the data from firebase but changing variable value locally. You cant just change the variable value and expect your database to update. You need to perform a `.update()` on the document. Info on how to update a document on CloudFirestore https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#updating-documents